# Expected number of steps to reach absorbing steps in a random walk.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose a Markov Chain, {$ X_n, n \ge 0$}, so that $P_{i,i+1} = P_{i,i-1} = 1/2$, for $0 < i < K$, and $P_{K, K} = P_{0, 0} = 1$.

How can I proof that the expected number of steps for reach $K$ or $0$, given that $X_0 = i$, is equal to $i(n-i)$?

Comment: Hi, since you are new, know that  you need to first show what you have tried and where you are stuck, so please edit in to get necessary help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: let $a_i$ the expected number of steps for reach $K$ or $0$ given $X_0 = i$, then can you prove that $$a_{i} = \frac{a_{i-1} + a_{i+1}}2$$ for $ 0 < i < K$? How about $a_0$? and $a_K$? Finally use induction.